# Sharepoint Online - Users and billing related edge case

Tags: sharepoint-online

My family runs a small printing-shop and I'm thinking about using sharepoint to build a simple portal where the costumers would register and upload what they want to print, instead of just sending via email. These users would register using some sort of external provider (facebook/gmail/yahoo) and would only be given permission on the "upload" part of the site...

My question here is: SharePoint Online supports this scenario without billing me for every costumer as if they were employees? I want to pay for my 4 employees and whatever storage I need, and no more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint Online supports sharing information with external users / customers without you having to pay extra for those (external) users/accounts.

However, this works only if one of your (4) paying users is 'inviting' the external user over to your SharePoint site. The external user will receive an invitation email. When they log in a Microsoft account will be created (or associated with an existing one) for this user (using his email-address as username)

An anonymous site is not allowed. Users always need to sign in.

Only 100 uploads supported at once. 2GB is maximum file size and certain file types are blocked for security reasons (dll, exe, shtml, json, asp, etc...)

There is also a maximum on the amount of external users but I believe that this depends on your SharePoint Online subscription. For the "Enterprise plan" it's 10.000 external users.

Comment: tks... I think sharepoint online is not the route for me here... any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with web building. 
You can still use SP Online as a back-office system. Let users fill out a request form (on a other site) and store the information directly in a SharePoint Online list. (using web services etc...)